# SOlr: how to calculate number of users in each age?

Tags: php, search, drupal, solr, full-text-search

I have a trie date field (ds_created) in solr, I have to calculate number of users in each age (18(6876),19(55464),20(545)...98(54566),100(88))

```
$params = array(
    'spellcheck' => 'false',   
    'wt' => 'json',
    'facet' => 'true',
    'facet.limit' => 100,
    'facet.mincount' => 0,
    'facet.range'=>'ms(NOW,ds_created)/(365*24*60*60*100)',
    'facet.range.gap'=>'+1DAY',
    'f.ds_created.facet.range.start'=>'2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
    'f.ds_created.facet.range.end'=>NOW,
    'rows' => '1',
    'start' => 0,
);

$query = apachesolr_drupal_query('apachesolr', $params);
$query->addFilter('bundle', 'node_name');
drupal_alter('apachesolr_query', $query);
$response = $query->search();
```